# Is "[location] welcome to" acceptable?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

The song *["Chałupy welcome to"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoXAywOx3u0)*, about a nudist beach near the seaside village of Chałupy was the hit of summer 1985 in Poland, with catchy, positive, light text for the dark times, and fun melody. Still, outside of the title of the song I've never seen the phrase used in that form. Normally, I think one would write *"Welcome to Chałupy"*, as a greeting to the village.

Is this alternate order acceptable or is it one glaring grammar error in the title?

Comment: May be an artistic license, perhaps.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how it would be phrased in Polish?

Comment: @StoneyB: "Witamy w Chałupach" (We welcome in Chałupy) or "Chałupy witają" (Chałupy welcome; the name is inherently plural so not "welcomes")

Comment: @SF. So presumably the lyricist is "internationalizing" *Chałupy witają*? Does that have the same cadence as the phrase in the song?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The grammatically correct word order in English would be

> Welcome to Chałupy

The reason why the song might (incorrectly) be referred to by some as "Chałupy welcome to" is due to the structure of the chorus in the song itself:

> Chałupy welcome to, Bahama Mama luz
>
> Afryka dzika dawno odkryta, Chałupy welcome to
>
> Chałupy welcome to, sun of Jamaica blues

Even in Polish this word order is wrong (the Polish would be "Witamy w Chałupach"), but it is used in order to achieve some rhymes and rhythmic ordering in the structure of the song itself, i.e. the author of the song is using a certain degree of artistic licence with regards  to the normal structuring of the sentence.

So in brief, the answer is no; the correct grammatical construction would be "Welcome to Chałupy".

Answer (score 5):

I would think that the normal way to translate this into English would be *Welcome to Chałupy,* or perhaps *Entering Chałupy*.

*Chałupy Welcome To* would be a very awkward and non-standard construct. If you really wanted to preserve the original word order for some reason, I'd suggest using a comma:

> *Chałupy, Welcome To*

This would make the awkward construct seem more deliberate and acceptable. It's not unlike what you might find in a book's index matter:

> Color, planning for
>   Columbine, wild
>   Coneflower, purple
>   Cornel, dwarf

Comment: To maintain the meter you'd have to employ a 'dynamic' translation: *Chalupy welcomes you!*